# Custom Update Function for Devise. Requiring current password only when updating password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I currently have a user that has extra attributes that I want them to be able to update without entering their current password.

So I had to create my own RegistrationsController and override the update method. (Taken from Devise github page).

```
  def update
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete('password')
      account_update_params.delete('password_confirmation')
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)

      set_flash_message :notice, :updated

      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path

    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

But now, I want to require them to put in their correct current password if they want to change their password. This seems to be an issue because if they do put in their current password, I have to add it to the permitted parameters. But then it tells me that current_password is not a valid attribute of the user.

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :attr1, :attr2,
                                                                   :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_with_password` and `update_without_password` mehotds

```
with_password = params[:current_password].present?

if @user.update_user(with_password)

  set_flash_message :notice, :updated

  # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
  sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path

else
  render 'edit'
end

private 
def update_user(with_password)
  if with_password
    @user.update_with_passoword(account_update_params)
  else
    @user.update_passoword(account_update_params)
  end
end
```

See [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable)

Comment: When I try to use "update_with_password", I get a flash message telling me that Current Password can't be blank. I'm not validating presence of it in my User model, where would I change that?

Comment: OK. I'll edit the answer, but basically. When you're provinding the password (current_password) to confirm the user crendentials.

When you're updating without the current_password, you cau use the update_withou_password method.